# Classifying space for finite-dimensional torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

Note that $K({\bf Z},1)=S^1$ but $BS^1 = {\bf CP}^\infty$.

For finite groups $H$, $G$, $$K(G\times H,1) = K(G,1)\times K(H,1)$$

Does it works for classifying spaces of continuous groups ?

As far as I know, $$BT^d\neq \prod_{i=1}^d {\bf CP}^\infty$$

What is $BT^d$ ?

And how can we prove $b_{2i} (BT^d, {\bf Q})=d^i$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$EG\times EH$ is a contractible space with free $G\times H$-action. The quotient by this action is $BG\times BH$. So $B(G\times H)\cong BG\times BH$ (in particular, $B(S^1)^d\cong\mathbb(CP^\infty)^d$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From your answer $b_4(BT^2,{\bf Q}) =3\neq  4$. So I cannot understand the proof of Theorem 4.1 in the paper " Torus actions on manifolds of positive sectional curvature - Wilking " (See http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/sfb/about/publ/wilking.html)

Comment: @user37116 The paper states (correctly) that $b_{2i}(BT^d)=\binom{i+d-1}i$; in particular, $b_4(BT^2)=\binom 31=3$. Where do you see the statement «$b_4(BT^2)=4$»?